# Trouble building/starting sentry and its database

Tags: python, sentry

[Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/)

I've been using this to setup the environment: [Sentry Setup](https://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/index.html#initializing-the-configuration)

But when I get to this command:

```
sentry --config=/etc/sentry.conf.py upgrade
```

It gives me this error:

```
nope@not_telling_you-ubuntu:~/scratch$ sudo sentry --config=/etc/sentry.conf.py upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sentry", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sentry==5.4.5', 'console_scripts', 'sentry')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentry-5.4.5-py2.7.egg/sentry/utils/runner.py", line 197, in main
    initializer=initialize_app,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/logan/runner.py", line 162, in run_app
    management.execute_from_command_line([runner_name, command] + command_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/logan/importer.py", line 68, in load_module
    return self._load_module(fullname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/logan/importer.py", line 92, in _load_module
    load_settings(self.config_path, allow_extras=self.allow_extras, settings=settings_mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/logan/settings.py", line 49, in load_settings
    execfile(mod_or_filename, conf.__dict__)
  File "/etc/sentry.conf.py", line 45, in <module>
    dgin
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: NameError("name 'dgin' is not defined",)
asdas@asdas-ubuntu:~/scratch$
```

Any idea what could be going on? I've setup everything until this point.

Comment: What's this got go do with PostgreSQL? I don't see anything relevant...

Comment: It uses that as it's database.

https://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/index.html#using-mysql-or-postgres

Comment: Sure; all I'm saying is that there's no apparent database-related issue here, it's all in higher levels of the stack.

Comment: Yea, got ya there. I only put in PostgreSQL because this part of the project deals with it and maybe someone would notice something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"dgin" is an undefined variable in the sentry configuration

It's likely this is a mistype or something similar, but that's what the error means.

Comment: Yup! Somehow it got into the file. Thanks